# Exact wording to commit to death penalty

Tags: halacha-theory, beit-din-court, maseches-sanhedrin

1. To incriminate a person for a capital sin requires a warning, to distinguish between intentional and unintentional transgression (שוגג או מזיד, Makot 6).
2. A person should be warned that the action he is about to perform constitutes a transgression and the punishment for that transgression is [one of the four types of] death.
3. To be sure the person understands the warning and carries the action intentionally he needs to reply with a certain wording ("שעל מנת כן אני עושה" - "that's exactly my intention").
4. If the person stays quiet or says something unclear he's not considered Mezid.

**The question(s):**

1. What does it mean "שעל מנת כן אני עושה" - intention to carry out despite the punishment or intention to be killed?
2. What is the general formula that can ensure he is Mezid? Are there special "stop-words"?

Comment: Could you please add for each point the exact location in the text?

Comment: what do you mean to be killed? The wrong doer should know exactly what the punishment is for Mezid and when he is warned of said punishment then he can be sentenced for it as Mezid.